# How to avoide android ANR

Tags: android

I have one library which is linked to my Android application, I am calling some functions of that lib from my android Activity and those function calls are time taking (4-5 seconds).

I can not call this functions in separate thread (using AsyncTaks, Threads) because of the library limitations.

When i call these function and when these function are in process at the same time my UI does not respond to user activities and to avoid that i am displaying processing screen and if in-between user performs any key actions then i get ANR error.

How can i avoid this ANR or there is no way i can avoid it other that putting time taking process in separate thread?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you cant run those calls on a separate Thread?

Comment: if i call it from separate Thread then my lib just crash. so i can't do it from Thread.

Comment: What library limitations are you talking about?? You can certainly do tasks same way in seperate threads or async tasks, if you can do it on UI thread.

Comment: I agree - you cannot overcome this problem except by solving the basic problem in the library

Comment: And what error does it show when app crashes??

Comment: in fact paste your logcat and put your code in which you are trying to use Threads. I think you might be doing something else wrong which is causing crash :)

Comment: no error it just a random crash so i can't use these calls in Thread.

Comment: There must be some Exception or error mentioned in logcat, right??

Comment: in readme of the lib they i have told us that it should not be called from other threads other than in which it is create/linked. and i have linked this lib in UI thread.

Comment: if in the requirements you are not supposed to use threads, then my friend **ANR is your ultimate fate!** :)

Comment: or a very last but not feasible option would be to target your app for Quad-Core processor phones. Perhaps they may help you to cut-off those 4/5 seconds :)

Comment: is there any way (I am using JNI for calling this time taking function) by which i will call one native (CPP) function from JNI which will inform native layer to call that time taking function and then Android activity will wait till time taking function called from native and then after it is done it will inform the java activity using JNI. can we do this in CPP can we have timer kind of machanisum which we will start from using JNI and when it timer expires it will call that time taking function.

Answer (score 0):

better read [**this**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html) article and watch google IO videos (like [**this**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-zippy-android-apps.html) one and [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8&feature=player_embedded#t=2863s) one) .

if you don't have time for this , simply remember this simple rule:

**long operations (like internet operations , DB operations , IO operations , and anything that could simply take longer than 5 seconds ) could cause ANR if they occur on the UI thread.**

for updating the UI , you must use the UI thread . if you need to do it after/during the long operation , use classes such as : [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) , [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , [View.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) , [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) .

Answer (score 0):

Who wrote the library and what is it? The only reason I can think of as to why it would throw an exception is that it is trying to update the UI from the thread that you call it on.  If the library methods take 4-5 seconds to compete then they should provide you with a callback mechanism that you can update your UI on the UI thread.

```
new Thread("Slow native process") {
    public void run() {
        // call your "time taking process", passing in the callback (you could implement in the outer class and pass "this"...)
        callNativeMethod( args, new YourCallbackInterface() {
            public void onResult( String response ) {
                activity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                    // update UI
                });
            }
        });
    }
 }.start();
```

Comment: there is a call back and this when task is done, i need to find out some way in native (CPP) layer to trigger that time taking call, so that Android Activity will just inform CPP layer (using JNI) that we need to call time taking function and it will return and CPP layer will call that time taking function and when done it will inform the java layer using JNI.

Comment: by "time taking call" do you mean that the call takes a lot of time to complete?